# Kendo Grid Style

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to style this kendo grid search box section. I would like to have the result on one line and the search text box on another with a larger input control. I also want to remove the border. Any one have any idea why this is not working. I can see that the `margin-bottom: 30px;` is working but the `width: 75%;` will not make the search box any bigger?

```
.k-searchbox {
    order: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    width: 75%;      
  }
.k-grid .k-toolbar {
    background-color: white;
    border-top-style: none;
}

https://dojo.telerik.com/@mcdevittnccn/aDUyicow
```

Comment: Kendo styles can be a pain to override sometimes, you can try changing the width to be:

width: 75% !important; 

To rule out the style being overridden, then adjust the selector specificity to be higher than the Kendo generated styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write it this way to prevent kendo default css overriding your custom style.

```css
.k-toolbar .k-searchbox.k-input {
  order: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  width: 75%;      
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to remove that border from the searchbox? it looks like its the grid border and not the searchbox

Comment: of course. i realized that there is little syntax error with css code. You should change "order: 1px solid #ccc;" to "border:none". this will delete the border you mentioned